# Change appendix subsection number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I am writing an article for an Elsevier journal.

In my paper, I have 8 sections and before the references, I have an appendix. I defined the Appendix section as `\section*{Appendix}` since the appendix should not have a number.

I want to add two subsections in the appendix and I want them to be numbered, i.e. I would like to have numbers like `A.1` and `A.2`. If, however, I define the subsections as `\subsection`, then the number I see is `8.A`. How can I change this to `A.1`?

Comment: You can switch and reset the numbering by `\appendix`. But you might jetzt problem with you references afterwards.

Comment: How about using the `\appendix` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `\appendix` command defined in your template?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
% Transition to appendix. Numbering is reset.
\appendix
\section{Appendix 1}
\subsection{Appendix subsection 1}
\section{Appendix 2}
\end{document}
```

[image: latex]

Comment: Yes, the template had an \appendix command I was not aware of!